# Cryptographic Hash function

Tags: cryptography, hash

How can I implement a cryptographic hash function using the block cipher? I was wondering whether I can use AES in cipher block chaining mode to achieve this.

Comment: Duplicate of, and well answered here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/turning-a-cipher-into-a-hashing-function

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against implementing this yourself. If you disagree, have a look at the [current existing AES implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_implementations); many libraries are available and it's likely that these will suit your needs.

Have a look at [Turning a cipher into a hashing function](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6472/turning-a-cipher-into-a-hashing-function) and [Description of the AES cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Description_of_the_cipher) on Wikipedia if you're interested how the algorithm works.